Granting container registry access to Gitlab deploy token
I've successfully created a Gitlab Deploy Token for my project, and I can use docker login with that token. I.e. the password works.
However, docker pull <project URL> fails with Error response from daemon: Head "<project URL>": denied: access forbidden. After a docker logout followed by a docker login using my own credentials instead, that same docker pull <project URL> succeeds.
My deducation is that the URL is correct, but the Deploy Token has insufficient permissions of some sort. The token "scopes" are read_repository, read_registry, read_package_registry (a pull should not require write). The token doesn't have an expiry date. What other permissions could cause Gitlab to reject the git pull after a succesfull login?
auth.log contains the following hint, which I can't map to any UI-accessible setting: "scope_type":"repository","requested_actions":["pull"],"authorized_actions":[]. Why is the scope_type not read_registry, and how is pull not a read access?
What this is not: CI pipeline, Project Access Token, Deploy key.
[edit] The same problem exists with a Group Access Token : "authorized_actions":[]
